# how to group by and transform the count back to the dataframe

Tags: pandas

Say I have the following df:

```
years = []
months = []
ys = [2003,2003,2004,2005]

for y in ys:
    for i in range(1,4):
        years.append(y)
        months.append(i)

df= pd.DataFrame({"year":years,'month':months})
df

    year    month
0   2003    1
1   2003    2
2   2003    3
3   2003    1
4   2003    2
5   2003    3
6   2004    1
7   2004    2
8   2004    3
9   2005    1
10  2005    2
11  2005    3
```

- note that 2003 repeats itself.

I wish to group by year and month and transform back to the df so the result would be:

```
    year    month   count
0   2003    1        1
1   2003    2        2
2   2003    3        3
3   2003    1        1
4   2003    2        2
5   2003    3        3
6   2004    1        4
7   2004    2        5
8   2004    3        6
9   2005    1        7
10  2005    2        8 
11  2005    3        9
```

I tired `df['count'] = df.groupby(['year','month']).transform('count')` but I get 'Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.ngroup()`:

```
df["count"] = df.groupby(["year", "month"]).ngroup() + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    year  month  count
0   2003      1      1
1   2003      2      2
2   2003      3      3
3   2003      1      1
4   2003      2      2
5   2003      3      3
6   2004      1      4
7   2004      2      5
8   2004      3      6
9   2005      1      7
10  2005      2      8
11  2005      3      9
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding another method with **`zip`** and **[`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)** which will return a unique number in sequence for each group:

```
df["count"] = pd.factorize([*zip(df['year'],df['month'])])[0]+1
```

Or using **[`df.records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html)** with `factorize`:

```
cols = ['year','month']
df["count"] = pd.factorize(df[cols].to_records(index=False))[0]+1
```

---

```
print(df)

    year  month  count
0   2003      1      1
1   2003      2      2
2   2003      3      3
3   2003      1      1
4   2003      2      2
5   2003      3      3
6   2004      1      4
7   2004      2      5
8   2004      3      6
9   2005      1      7
10  2005      2      8
11  2005      3      9
```